# repeating set row values for unique column values

Tags: for-loop, repeat

the data format i have is as follows: 
When i use s2<- fill_(s1,c("Time")), it would use the last seen value..
however i would like all values of time listed below to repeat for each value of Animal

```js
Group Animal Sex Time
1   1001   M   0
             4
             8
             24
             48
  
   
1 1002 M 
   
   
   
  
   
1 1003 M
```